Airflow with Docker Compose - Containers Stuck in "Starting" State with High CPU/Memory Usage
I'm encountering an issue with a Docker Compose deployment where multiple services, including Apache Airflow, are constantly stuck in the "starting" state. My docker-compose.yml file defines several services, including Apache Airflow, Redis, and PostgreSQL. The EC2 instance running these containers is a t3a.xlarge with 16 Gib and AMD EPYC 7571 with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I am sharing a screenshot of the resource usage for reference:
resource usage
and a screenshot of the issue :
containers restarting
What I've Tried:
I've checked the logs for the containers, but they don't provide a clear error message indicating why the services fail to fully start.
I've limited the resources (CPU and memory) for the containers in the docker-compose.yml file, but this hasn't resolved the issue.
I've stopped and restarted the containers, as well as the EC2 instance, without success.
Is there any Docker Compose configuration or setting that I may have overlooked which could cause this behavior?
Are there specific techniques to diagnose Docker containers stuck in a "starting" loop and to reduce excessive resource usage?
Should I consider resizing my EC2 instance, or are there other optimizations I should attempt before doing so?
Thank you for your help.
Here my my docker-compose.yml :
`version: "3"
x-airflow-common: &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.8.1}
  environment: &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ""
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: "true"
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "false"
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: "airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth"
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST: "smtp.gmail.com"
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT: 587
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER: "javiertest592@gmail.com"
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD: "${SMTP_PASSWORD}"
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM: "javiertest592@gmail.com"
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:- pymongo}
  volumes:
  - ../ETL:/opt/airflow/ETL
  - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
  - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
  - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy
  networks:
    - airflow-net  # Référence au réseau airflow-net

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    networks:
      - airflow-net  # Référence au réseau airflow-net

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always
    networks:
      - airflow-net  # Référence au réseau airflow-net

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    networks:
      - airflow-net  # Référence au réseau airflow-net

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"',
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    networks:
      - airflow-net  # Référence au réseau airflow-net

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    networks:
      - airflow-net  # Référence au réseau airflow-net

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: "true"
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
    networks:
      - airflow-net  # Référence au réseau airflow-net

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    networks:
      - airflow-net  # Référence au réseau airflow-net

networks:
  airflow-net:
    external: true  # Définir le réseau comme externe

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:`


can you disable health check for all the service in your docker compose and try to run it for the test and let me know what happens

Hi I removed the healthcheck sections from all services and restarted the containers, but they (airflow-scheduler_1, airflow-webserver_1, airflow-worker_1, airflow_flower_1) are still restarting.
